# How to pass a VLA to a function template?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, variable-length-array, gcc-extensions

I have the following code which could not be complied.

```
using namespace std;
void f(int);
template<typename T1, size_t N>
void array_ini_1d(T1 (&x)[N])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    x[i] = 0;
  }
}
```

What is the proper way to pass the array if the main is something like below.

```
int main()
{
  int a;
  cin >> a;
  int n = a / 4;
  f(n);
  return 0;
}

void f(int n)
{
  int arr[n];
  array_ini_1d(arr);
}
```

error: no matching function to call to array_ini_1d..............

Comment: What error do you get? Note that you can zero-initialize the elements of the array like this: `int arr[10] = {};`

Comment: Shouldn't be anything wrong with the code as long as `size_t` is defined. As the question stands now, the answer is 'that is the correct way'. More info is needed to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Compiles for me. What error do you have? What compiler do you use?

Comment: You need to include e.g. `<stddef.h>` for `size_t` (or `<cstddef>` and say `using std::size_t`) to guarantee that your code sample compiles without further changes.

Comment: i'm calling this function inside another function. is it ok?

Comment: @user29561 Yes, that is OK. Please post a simple code sample that reproduces the problem. Otherwise we're just guessing :)

Comment: error:no matching func to call to

Comment: Two things: you are missing a `;` at the declaration `void f(int)`, and the standard does not support automatic storage arrays with a runtime determined size, although your compiler *might* allow it as an extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the compiler can deduce the size of a variable-length array in a template. Also, don't forget to forward declare `f` before you use it. Variable-length arrays are a GCC extension and you should get a warning regarding their use.

Comment: I don't think `iostream` is guaranteed to define `size_t`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Maybe. I found this in the standard (not sure if it's out of context): `However, referring to std or std::size_t is ill-formed unless the name has been declared
by including the appropriate header. — end note ] `

Comment: As per the standard `std::size_t` is defined in `<cstddef>` (usualy as the same as `::size_t` in `<stddef.h>`.  iostrem often use it, but the standard does not require `streampos` to be the same (or compatible with...) size_t. It is just a very common immplementation on platform having size_t as 64 bit unsigned, but not a standard requirement. So, in fact "iostream" does not grant for size_t to be defined

Comment: @Emilio It seems this answer is invalidated with the new edit anyway.

Comment: The point is that `std::size_t` may even not be the same as `::size_t`, although no implementer will ever make them distinct, otherwise the most of the existing cod will break...

Comment: But since arrays are from C and the size is the difference of two pointers, the proper way to describe it is `::size_t` and not `std::size_t`, wich is much more related as a bridge towards traits classes, allocators and containers

Comment: @Emilio I thought `<cstddef>` just includes `<stddef.h>` and then wraps it into `std`. As long as the OP doesn't use `using namespace std;`, there should be no conflicts, right?

Comment: @remyabel: yes, this is what all the implementations do. But that's not a specification: the C++ standard doesn't say where `std::size_t` must come from. It just says it "must be wide enough to measure the distance of two pointers". C does the same for `::size_t`, but there is nothing is the specification requirement that says they have to be the same

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that variable size arrays are not supported by c++, and is only supported as compilers extension. That means, the standard doesn't say what should happen, and you should see if you can find in compiler's documentation, but I doubt that such corner cases are documented.

So, this is the problem :

```
int arr[n];
```

The solution is to avoid it, and use something supported by c++, like for example `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

You may declare your function like this:

```
template <typename A, size_t N> void f(A a[N]) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
        cout << a[i];
}
```

However, the problem is that when you call the function, the compiler won't deduce the template parameters, and you will have to specify them explicitly.

```
char arr[5] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};

int main()
{
    //f(arr); //Won't work
    f<char, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])>(arr);
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, that ruins the very idea...

**UPD:** And even that code does NOT work for an array that has variable length, for the length is calculated at runtime, and the template parameters are defined at compilation time.

**UPD2:** If using `std::vector` you may create it initialized:
`vector<int> arr(n, 0);`
Or you may fill it with `fill` from `<algorithm>` when needed:
`std::fill(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 0);`

Comment: Well yeah, the OP is trying to create a local VLA. He's passing the size of the array to the function anyway, so why can't just pass it along to `array_ini_1d`? There's no reason for the templates except for the deduction trick, which is defeated by the usage of VLAs.

Answer (score 1):

As you use Variable length array (VLA) (compiler extension), compiler cannot deduce N.

You have to pass it by pointer and give the size:

```
template<typename T>
void array_ini_1d(T* a, std::size_t n)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
        a[i] = 0;
    }
}

void f(int n)
{
    int arr[n];
    array_ini_1d(arr);
}
```

Or use `std::vector`. (no extension used so). Which seems cleaner:

```
template<typename T>
void array_ini_1d(std::vector<T>& v)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0, size = v.size(); i != n; ++i) {
        a[i] = 0; // or other stuff.
    }
}

void f(int n)
{
    std::vector<int> arr(n); // or arr(n, 0).
    array_ini_1d(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Template parameters must be resolved at compile-time.

There is no way that a function template with parameter `size_t N` can match any sort of array or other container whose size comes from a run-time input.

You will need to provide another version of the `array_1d_ini` which does not have the size as a template parameter.

Answer (score -1):

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
void f(T* a)
{
/* add your code here */
}

int main()
{
    int a[10];
    f<int, 10>(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP's solution works for fixed-size array. But OP uses compiler extension for VLA.